# How to use maven-docker on development-environment to avoid repeated download jars?

Tags: java, maven, docker, docker-compose, development-environment

this is my Dockerfile,but if I changed the java code ,and then enter "docker-compose up -d --build" to terminal,maven will re-download the jars, how to avoid duplication of the download?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.5.0-jdk-8
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
RUN mvn verify
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","target/cloud-user.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "2"
services:
  cloud-nginx:
    build: cloud-nginx
    image: registry.cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/wangdali/cloud-nginx
    restart: always
    ports: ["80:80"]
  cloud-consul:
    image: consul:0.9.2
    command: consul agent -dev -client 0.0.0.0
  cloud-front:
    build: cloud-front
    image: registry.cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/wangdali/cloud-front
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./cloud-front/static:/app
  cloud-user:
    build: cloud-user
    image: registry.cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/wangdali/cloud-user
    restart: always
  mysql: 
    image: mysql:5.7.19
    hostname: mysql
    volumes: 
      - ./docker/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql 
      - ./docker/mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d 
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
    ulimits: 
      nproc: 65535
    mem_limit: 1024m 
    restart: always 
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
```

---

I streamlined my test project, and then use the spring-boot plugin for maven

> mvn spring-boot:run

to start the project, now that mount .m2 folder first and then run mvn command. 
But after I changing the java source code ,it does not loading automatically by devtools, how to solve?

and this is my Dockerfile/docker-compose.yml :

Dockerfile:

```
version: "2"
services:
  user:
    build: user
    volumes:
      - $HOME/.m2/repository:/root/.m2/repository
      - ./user/src:/app/src
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
FROM maven:3.5.0-jdk-8
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
ENTRYPOINT ["mvn","spring-boot:run"]
```

Comment: Mount the local cach `$HOME/.m2/repository` into your docker image...But why are you building inside a Docker container? Why not simply copying the final resulting war/jar file into the Docker container via Dockerfile?

Comment: @khmarbaise Originally, I wanted to add jar and run it in the container, but the code changes more frequently during development, and the process seems too tedious. Then I thought of putting $HOME/.m2/repository as a data volume in the container, but I tried many times and didn't figure out how to mount .m2 directory into the container before executing mvn verify.

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved, I mount target folder to container,it's can be automatically loaded, which is the final dockerfile and docker-compose.yml, of course, in the production environment, we can not write:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.5.0-jdk-8
WORKDIR /app
COPY pom.xml .
COPY src ./src
ENTRYPOINT ["mvn","spring-boot:run"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  user:
    build: user
    volumes:
      - $HOME/.m2/repository:/root/.m2/repository
      - ./user/target:/app/target
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "5005:5005"
```

pom.xml:

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>cn.codeforfun.Application</mainClass>
          <jvmArguments>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</jvmArguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: A note of advice. Using docker-compose, you can use a named volume for m2, so instead of mounting your own .m2 directory, you can use a volume: (volumes:\n -m2data:/root/.m2/repository) and then under a volumes section specify the m2data. When you compose up and down it will keep the volume around so each consecutive start will reuse your dependencies. You can delete the volume manually or by adding -v to docker-compose down command. Hope I make sense without the formatting.

Comment: @NielsBechNielsen Thank you very much. Your advice has been a great inspiration to me, I guess  I need to try more times.